# I need to compare two different lines with 2 or more than strings using if command

Tags: tcsh

i have tried like this:

```
#tcsh
set a="abc jue"
set b="sdc asj"
if($a == $b)then
    echo "match"
else
    echo"unmatch"
endif
```

this one is not working

Comment: How do you run it, and what do you see it do? If there are error messages please include them in your question. (Do not reply here in the comments.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set a = "abc jue"
set b = "sdc asj"
if ( "$a" == "$b" ) then
    echo "match"
else
    echo "unmatch"
endif
```

more information about tcsh [here](http://www.oocities.org/gurucoder/Tools/sys/tcsh_syntax.txt)

Comment: thank you for the reply but this one is not working, even i tried with $#a==$#b, and that also not giving the expected output

Comment: @arj "_not giving the expected output_" is an almost useless statement. Nowhere have you told us what you expected output should be. This script segment will print `unmatch`. Why isn't that expected? Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION to explain what it is that you want from your (or this) code.